# GPS Logger problem

Tags: arduino-uno

I have some problems with my GPS Logger. U use Arduino Uno, NEO - 6M, SD card.
Problem is in function void loop. I enter inside, but stuck on the "while loop", don't even get inside this loop. Here is code I use:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define SD_CS 4
#define FILE_BASE_NAME "Trac"

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial serial(10, 11);

File myFile;

const uint8_t BASE_NAME_SIZE = sizeof(FILE_BASE_NAME) - 1;
char fileName[] = FILE_BASE_NAME "00.csv";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("SD card initialization...");
  if(!SD.begin(SD_CS))
  {
    Serial.println("Failed! Check card");
    //while(1);
  }
  Serial.println("Initialization done");

  while (SD.exists(fileName)){
    if (fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1] != '9') 
    {
      fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1]++;
    } 
    else if (fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE] != '9') 
    {
      fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE + 1] = '0';
      fileName[BASE_NAME_SIZE]++;
    } 
    else{
      Serial.println("Can't create file name");
      //return;
    }
  }

  myFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  if (!myFile) {
    Serial.println("open failed");
    //return;
  }
  Serial.print("opened: ");
  Serial.println(fileName);
}

void loop(){
  while (serial.available())
  {
    int c = serial.read();
    if (gps.encode(c))
    {
      long lat, lon;
      unsigned long fix_age;
      gps.get_position(&lat, &lon, &fix_age);
      Serial.print("Latitude:");Serial.println(lat);
      Serial.print("Longitude:");Serial.println(lon);
      myFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);  
      myFile.print(lat);
      myFile.print(", ");
      myFile.print(lon);
      myFile.println("");
      myFile.close();
    }
  }
}
```

If I use this code, it gives me the lat ad lon:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial nss(10, 11);

void setup(){
  nss.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  while (nss.available())
  {
    int c = nss.read();
    if (gps.encode(c))
    {
      long lat, lon;
      unsigned long fix_age;
      gps.get_position(&lat, &lon, &fix_age);

      Serial.print("Szerokosc:");Serial.println(lat);
      Serial.print("Dlugosc:");Serial.println(lon);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to describe the observed results .... you made no mention if anything actually prints in the serial monitor

Comment: Yes sorry, the observed results:
-code with GPS only is print location on serial monitor, so GPS works fine
-code with GPS and SD card only show inforation about file create and stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD uses SPI. [On the Uno, SPI is on pins 10-13](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI). You are also using pins 10 and 11 for software serial. That won't work. You need to use pins other than 10 and 11 for software serial.

Comment: Owww that was so simple, and stupid mistake for me. You saved my life! Thanks so much.

First I changed the pins of serial to 8 and 9, it's not work, but when I change to 5 and 6 it works perfectly. Once again thanks! :)